# programmatically populating the QGIS Legend

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, legend

So I have a function in a utility class that creates my Legend for the composer. It looks something like this:

```
def addLegend(self, c, r, L, tree_root):
    L.model().setLayerSetAndGroups(tree_root)
    c.addComposerLegend(L)
```

where:

1. L is an QgsComposerLegend
2. c is the QgsComposition
3. r is the iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
4. tree_root is an arbitrary group in the tree of layers and groups originating from QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

it works but my requirements bring up these issues:

1. The legend should display a colored box for the groups
2. The layers should not show up in the legend even though they do in the map

Comment: Even though they are unmarked you seem to be asking two questions which makes this too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by applying a single color to all the polygons captured by my query across layers. Then I created a legend folder into which I added stub memory polygon layer with a zero dimension polygon giving it the corresponding query's color. I then pass this group to the legend for processing.

Comment: Did you do this programmatically? Could you share your code?

Comment: I think that the answer to a coding question is always far better if it includes code.